# Edit and Update Existing Features in a Collector App using Survey123 Forms

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, arcgis-survey123

I have an existing polyline dataset that needs to be reviewed and have certain attributes populated by field personnel. We have a hosted feature layer in Collector, and are attempting to use a Survey123 form to do the review as the form has much greater customization and further capabilities than simply editing in Collector.

The ideal workflow would be:

1. Click feature in Collector to bring up a custom pop-up
2. Click custom url in pop-up to launch Survey123 field app with certain fields populated.
3. Submit survey to populate/overwrite attributes in the existing feature.

url: arcgis-survey123://?itemID=123455abcdefg&mode=edit&globalId={GlobalID}&objectId={OBJECTID}&field:PermId={PermId) etc...

Where I am getting hung up is apparently you cannot use the mode=edit parameter with the Survey123 Field App, only a Survey123 web form? Trying to use these parameters in the Field App url still is adding a new record in the underlying table rather than updating it. Is there a way to either have the form submission overwrite an existing record or open survey123 straight in the inbox rather than a new survey?

We want to use the map capabilities and interface of the collector app with the form customization and data validation abilities of the Survey123 app. We cannot use a web form to edit the features (frustratingly, since that seems to work fine) as some of the personnel will be working in areas without data connection. We need the offline capabilities of the Field App.

Comment: Which version of Survey are you using? Have you tried removing the `objectId` parameter? [Depending on the version you are using](https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2020/02/19/upcoming-changes-to-survey123-web-forms-query-parameters), that parameter might not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but mode=edit only exists with web version. you cant pass that to survey. What you can do is reference all the data and pass that over with `"&field={field}&field2={field2}..."`

Everyone wants the survey123-collector overlap.  ESRIs answer is Field Maps which is now available. Just hope no one uses a Windows device.

Field maps will allow you to group and set visibilities for questions using arcade expressions.  Its a more refined Collector.